# Change/remove default marking/focus on elements

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I have the following simple Java Swing app:

[image]

My button "New button" is marked/focused per default, but I would like to change/remove that default marking.

How do I do that?

Comment: Take a look at the [Focus Subsystem Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html).

Comment: Nothing else on that GUI is focusable.  Why should the button not have focus?  Also see [How do I create screenshots?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99734/how-do-i-create-a-screenshot-to-illustrate-a-post) (for tips on making *great* screenshots).

Comment: @Andrew Thompson

What's wrong with the screenshot?

Comment: 1) I didn't say it was 'wrong' it is just not a *great* screenshot - specifically covered in that linked advice by **Use a plain background** & **Image size** 2) What's wrong with answering my question?

Comment: @Andrew Thompson I think you're way of with the hairsplitting as the background is almost not-visible and the size of the image is actually pretty decent when taking the problem/question into consideration.
There's no specific reason why the button should not have focus ATM, but it's nice to know if required in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I would like to change/remove that default marking.

is possible to change this property by

- [JButton#setFocusPainted(boolean b)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setFocusPainted%28boolean%29)
- [JButton#setFocusable(boolean focusable)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setFocusable%28boolean%29)